# multiprocessing in python not running multiple core in big list

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

When I am loading a small list from the file system during the execution, multiprocessor works fine. 8 cores are running simultaneously. However when I load a very big list from a file system during the execution only 3 cores are running. I think it is because processor are waiting to copy the list to every processor.

Is there anyway to force the processor to access the list concurrently?

tokenization.py

```
def compute_customizedStopwords():
    stopword_dictionary = open(BASE_DIR + "/app1/NLP/Dictionary/humanDecisionDictionary.txt",'r')
    customizedStopwords = set()
    # compute stopwords set 
    for line in stopword_dictionary:
        customizedStopwords.add(line.strip('\n').lower()
    return customizedStopwords

def tokenize_task(narrative, customizedStopwords)
    tokens = narrative.corpus.split(",")
    tokens = [token for token in tokens if token not in customizedStopwords]  # remove stopwords
    newTokenObjects = [ Token(token = token) for token in tokens] 
    Token.objects.bulk_create(newTokenObjects) # save all tokens to database
    return tokens
```

views.py

```
def tokenize(request) :
    narratives = models.Narrative.objects.all() # get all documents 
    customizedStopwords = compute_customizedStopwords() # get stopwords set
    pool = Pool()
    results = [pool.apply(tokenize_task, args=(narrative, customizedStopwords)) for narrative in narratives]
    tokens = []
    tokens += results # flat the token list
    return HttpResponse(tokens)
```

Comment: Write the list into the file and allow each process to read their part of data from that file. Or do it with pipes.

Comment: @baldr Actually, each process needs to access whole file.

Comment: Could you show some parts of the code where you do this?

Comment: @baldr please look at the edit for the code

Comment: Firstly, you'd better to use stopword_dictionary.readlines() - this will read entire file into the memory as a list instead of reading line-by-line.
Secondly, you can move this part into tokenize_task() function to let processes to read the file themselves.

Comment: I'm voting for never working in parallel because you use `tools.apply`. From the docs _It blocks until the result is ready. Given this blocks, apply_async() is better suited for performing work in parallel._.